# switch row and colums in data.frame, convert large list to data.frame, Convert Mixed-Length named List to data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a large list (220559 elements) into a data frame. Each element is either chr (RT) or chr(0) 
I tried:

```
data.frame(t(sapply(my.list, c)))
```

I got the data frame, but it turned out to be one observation with 220559 variables instead of one variable with 220559 observations.

Is there an easy way to switch the observations with the variables? Or do I have to create the data frame differently? I'm new to R and really looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a giant list where is element is either the character "RT" or is it an empty character vector (`character(0)`). And you want to turn this into a data frame with one row and one column for each item in the list (220559 columns).

The problem is that data.frames like all columns to have the same number of observations (rows). And `length("RT")==1` while `length(character(0))==0`. So you can either drop those columns, or convert those values to `NA`. I'm going to assume the latter for my example.

```
# "large" list
xx<-sample(list(character(), "RT"), 1000, replace=T)

#make into data.frame
df<-data.frame(lapply(xx, function(x) if(length(x)==0) NA else x))

#add nicer names
names(df)<-paste0("V",seq_along(df))
```

That's it. Normally to turn a list into a `data.frame` you just call `data.frame()`. It was just a bit trickier because of your zero-length vectors.